# collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]

Tags: c, linux, ld, ubuntu-18.04

I actually can not compile a simple "helloworld" in C. When I type "gcc hello.c" the output is: 
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]

Have someone an idea?

I tried to reinstall gcc,g++,make,cmake,binutils. None of this things worked. 
When I type just "ld" in the terminal the output is:
"Segmentation Fault"

Comment: Which version of Linux?  Which versions of the GCC and the binutils have you upgraded to?  Have you run `which ld` to check that it runs what you think it should be running?

Comment: /usr/bin/ld
gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0 
I can't answer for the version of binutils because ld -v give me a Segmentation Fault

Comment: Does `ld —version` crash too?  If so, your installation (of `ld` and maybe all of binutils) is seriously broken. But what it takes to fix it is also unclear given that you’ve fully updated your system.  Maybe consider removing both GCC and binutils before reinstalling them?

Comment: ld -version is also a Segmentation Fault. I also removed (with purge) gcc and binutils and then installed it new. but it didn't work.

Comment: I dunno if my iPhone converted two dashes before `version` into a single long dash.  I also have no idea whether it’ll make any difference. Normally, the development tools are very reliable; they’re the first thing tested when building a system.  So what you’re seeing is abnormal.  What I’m not sure is how to help you fix it.  The normal techniques don’t seem to work.

Comment: What are all your environment variables?  Especially any of the `LD_*` ones?  Post the output from `env | grep LD` to start.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065480/compiler-gives-error-ld-terminated-with-signal-11#57065480 is a **very** similar issue.

Answer (score 6):

I could solve it with

```
sudo apt purge binutils
sudo apt remove make
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install build-essential
```

I don't know why it works with build-essential...

Comment: as listed in `info` the correct 'package' to install is `build-essential`  not `binutils'`

Answer (score 1):

You may be hitting this old issue. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1557346 (from March 2018, and binutils 2.25, 2.27).

Update your binutils.

For example:

```
# yum groupinstall Development Tools
```

or

```
# apt-get install build-essential
```

and Install Kernel Source

```
# apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: This sounds plausible.

Comment: can u paste the versions of gcc,g++,make,cmake,binutils ? and os details

Comment: gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
cmake version 3.10.2

Comment: as @Jonathan told,  your `ld` may going wrong then. did you confirmed ld is `/usr/bin/ld`

here is another [link](https://lfs-dev.linuxfromscratch.narkive.com/LbkNCRTA/collect2-ld-terminated-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault-core-dumped) same problem

Comment: That second link is from 18 years ago. It is unlikely to be the problem in Ubuntu 18.04 which is the current LTS release.

Comment: i just installed 18.04.2, i dont hav any such problems.(After installing new OS, i just installed vim and gcc). one of the reply he mentioned that `ld -v` resulting segmentation fault. i am suspecting his binutil packages. user can reinstall that package (apt-get remove and apt-get install) and try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated any of your library?
I think there might be some library missing in this case. Try doing the following :

```
which gcc
```

You will get output as :

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Then check the library using :

```
ldd /usr/bin/gcc
```

This will give you the library as well as its shared object. Check if all are available.

Also check gcc version to check if 'gcc' binary is working.

```
gcc --version
```

Comment: A missing library rarely if ever causes the `ld` command to dump core.

Comment: I tried also this. But there is no missing library and I have the newest gcc

Comment: gcc --version is working..?? Providing the output..??