# compiler gives error ld terminated with signal 11

Tags: c, gcc, linker, ld, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to compile a simple hello program using gcc, but getting the below error. i am using ubuntu.

gcc -g -o hello hello.c

> collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation
>   fault], core dumped compilation terminated.

strace ld -v

> execve("/usr/bin/ld", ["ld", "-v"], 0x7ffc43b744c8 /* 57 vars */) = 0
>   --- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x2} ---
>   +++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++ Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I tried reinstalling gcc and binutils, didn't work.

Comment: Either you are running out of memory, or you have bad RAM. Those are the two most likely explanations, based on the information given in the question.

Comment: Show your code. In [mcve] form preferably.

Comment: Try a different gcc version

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why would that help? You are just guessing..

Comment: @JesperJuhl Because the segfault is not caused by the OPs program but by `ld`. Meaning that it is buggy, or there is some OS/HW issue.

Comment: Still worth adding the MCVE, though. Someone could see the code and go, "Oh. THAT bug." Also add the output of `gcc -v` so we know what gcc we're dealing with.

Comment: Interestingly similar question from earlier today:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57051568/collect2-fatal-error-ld-terminated-with-signal-11-segmentation-fault#comment100635128_57051568  Also Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: What are the various `LD_*` environment variables set to?  Can you add the output from `env | grep LD_`?

Comment: @user4581301 clearly, gcc has nothing to do with this. `ld -v` already segfaults. I'd count that as a minimal example

Comment: Nothing worked. I tried everything I could think of like reinstalling build-essentials, gcc, binutils etc. I re installed the ubuntu now. Should I delete this question?